# Backbone + Handlebars: template not getting the data

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm sending data from my backbone view to a handlebars template (js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8NhjD/) like this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template({
        users: that.users.toJSON(),
        audiences: that.audiences.toJSON()
}));
```

and I'm trying to access the list of users and audiences like this:

```
<select name="user" class = "form-control">
{{#each users}}
    <option value="{{name}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

But the dropdown menus for the users and audiences are empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: good point! http://jsfiddle.net/8NhjD/

Comment: Are you really storing your templates in a `<div>`?

Comment: @muistooshort - yes, is that not a good practice?

Comment: Templates are rarely valid HTML (they're just text that sort of looks like HTML) so you should store them in `<script type="text/x-handlebars">` containers to keep the browser's hands off them.

Comment: Stuffing them into `<head>` is also a good idea so that you don't accidentally overwrite them while manipulating your page's content.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing in the models, which do not expose their attributes directly. Try something like this:

```
this.$el.html(this.template({
        users: that.users.toJSON(),
        audiences: that.audiences.toJSON()
}));
```

**UPDATED**:

Without a complete fiddle, it is hard to see where you went wrong. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moderndegree/qW7Tz/

HTML:

```
<script id="thing-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ul>
    {{#each things}}
    <li>{{this.thing}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
<div id="thing-view"></div>
```

JS:

```
var ThingModel = Backbone.Model.extend({}),
    ThingCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ThingModel
    }),
    ThingView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#thing-view',
        template: Handlebars.compile($("#thing-template").html()),
        initialize: function(){
            this.things = new ThingCollection([{thing: 'purple'}, {thing: 'monkey'}, {thing: 'dishwasher'}]);
        },
        render: function(){
            console.log(this.things.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(this.template({
                things: this.things.toJSON()
            }));
            return this;
        }
    });
var view = new ThingView().render();
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with a more thorough example

Answer (score 0):

Moving the collection-fetching from the view's initialize method to the route-handler resolved the issue.